# Wake and unlock Android phone screen when compile and run project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

When build and run iOS app using Xcode, the phone becomes awake and app runs. Is there a way to wake and unlock Android phone (or tablet) screen then run installed Android app (Eclipse, Android Studio)?

Comment: not that i know of, but you can set the device's screen to stay awake as long as it's connected. go to "developers options" and then "stay awake". BTW, the reason it's not awakening is that apps can be installed even when the device's screen is turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better and easiest solution is use the option (in development section) that the screen never goes off  I thing the name is "Stay awake". This option prevent your phone to get locked when the usb cable is connected.

Comment: but continues screen will utilize battery more..isn't it ? Although its charging, But wont it have a bad effect on device's life ?

Comment: I used to do it this way, but over time my screen started to get spotted. In long term, its not a good solution

Answer (score 19):

One solution: set the following flags in your activity class(es):

```
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        // These flags cause the device screen to turn on (and bypass screen guard if possible) when launching.
        // This makes it easy for developers to test the app launch without needing to turn on the device
        // each time and without needing to enable the "Stay awake" option.
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    }
```

These flags will:

1. Turn on the screen
2. Bypass the lock-screen
3. Allow showing the activity even if the device is locked

By setting those flags in your base activity, you'll be able to continue using your application even if the device was off and/or locked at the time of running. If you try to leave your application's process (i.e., hitting the home button, or switching to another app), the lock screen will appear, and you'll have to manually unlock to continue using the device.

***Warning*: this should only be used while developing/debugging your application, so I recommend keeping the `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` check, as it is in this example**

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since this solve exactly what was asked.

Comment: this flag can also be added 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Comment: The problem with `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` is that the screen will remain on after the app runs. In my case (and to resolve strictly what OP asked for), I only wanted the screen to turn on at the time of running, but NOT stay on perpetually (has a tendency to run down the battery or make the device hot, if I forget to start using it). Usually when I run the app, I just want the screen to come on so that I can start using it the way I need to, and beyond that it should turn itself off with the normal screen timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write a script which runs before the app deploys and unlocks the device. This requires no app code change and will not change screen timeout which can have security implications.
You can find the full setup [here](https://build3r.github.io/2021/08/01/auto_unlock_on_app_run.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
# When a device is attached there will be atleast 3 lines -> heading, device details, an empty new line
if adb devices | wc -l | grep "3"; then 
  # Check if device locked, this may differ on some OEMs
  if adb shell dumpsys window | grep  "mInputRestricted=true"; then 
      echo "Device is Locked"
      adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP # wakeup device
      adb shell input touchscreen swipe 530 1420 530 1120 # swipe up gesture
      adb shell input text "000000" # <- Change to the your device PIN/Password
      #adb shell input keyevent 66 # simulate press enter, if your keyguard requires it
  else
      echo "Device already unLocked"
  fi
  # 2 = Stay awake on USB, 0 = reset
  adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 2
  #adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 700
  adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
  adb shell input touchscreen tap 0 0 # this will wake up the screen and won't have any unwanted touches
else
  echo "There should be only one device connected at a time"
fi

return 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant unlock and wake the phone as that would not be very secure, however you can enable "Stay awake" in developer options.